# Passing Data to View Master Pages

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, master-pages

I am following the tutorial to pass data to view master page using the "good solution" from this link
http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc/tutorial-13-cs.aspx
but after doing the changes as instructed, when i run the application. the application run the action result from homecontroller. Should i made change in homecontroller, i am missing something

Comment: What is the real problem? Please explain more.

Answer (score 0):

My guess: You need to inherit from the `ApplicationController`

```
 public class HomeController : ApplicationController
 {
   ...
 }
```